# CSS - input (text and button) aligned differently in FF and Safari

Tags: css

i try to align a button and a text input on one level, but i get different results in Firefox (aligned properly) and Safari (not aligned properly).

I created a JSFiddle and you can see the different behavior in both browsers, but at the moment i can not say why this is happening.

Does someone know the answer?

Thanks!

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LPgJr/2/

Answer (score 2):

You want to float them both left - http://jsfiddle.net/LPgJr/3/

Don't forget to clear your floats afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. But this is strange. In the JSFiddle it looks fine, but when i transfer it to my project the Button in Safari is 3px higher than in Firefox. In FF it is aligned properly and everything is fine. In Safari the button is positioned 3px higher than in FF. I have a gap at the bottom and it is higher at the top.

Comment: I tried different margins and paddings and now it seems to work properly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that tweaking margins and paddings is the best approach.  If you want a particular alignment consider positioning or explicitly setting height, like SpaceBeers suggests.

Comment: Exactly. Either set equal heights equal paddings / margins or you'll end up with some wacky. Cross browser results.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit and Gecko render the heights of the text field differently, that's for sure.  Try, in your fiddle, successively changing the padding of the text field.  Try 0px, 1px, 2px, then 3px, 10px, 25px, 40px, 80px, anything.  You can see that the padding on the text field affects the vertical position of the button.  The larger the padding on the text field, the lower the button drops.

Why is this?  Because the browsers are lining up the text in the text area with the text on the button.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/LPgJr/6/

The browsers are giving different appearances because of the way they render text fields.  Set the height explicitly, as suggested by SpaceBeers.